# Is there a way to change a Salesforce ID?

Tags: salesforce-id, app

Salesforce generates and manages the  15-18 character Salesforce IDs for objects in their system.

We are getting a super weird error where our system can't handle an ID coming in from a customers installation of our Salesforce app. The ID that is being passed in is a 6 digit number.

We are 99% sure that you can't change the ID of a Salesforce object, and that somewhere our app is generating an incorrect ID, but just wanted to sanity check myself.

Is there a way to change the 15-18 character Salesforce ID for an object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short of cloning the object, and deleting the original, I know of no way to change the GUID for an SF Object.

Perhaps we ( the community ) could be of more help figuring out how to get your system to accept the object?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Short of posting all the code which I can't do :), we just need to work through it. Thanks for saving my sanity, wince we now know that the customer can't change the ID it is definitely on our side.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. There is only 1 Id type, the 15 character version and the 18 character version.

15 character version is case sensitive,
18 character version is case non-sensitive.

Can you confirm you are not pulling in the name of the sobject / table? This field could be set to auto increment. IE: SF-0001, SF-0002, etc

Comment: The ID is not SF-0003 etc. It was a straight 6 digit number. 345648.

Comment: This can still be the Name field on that Sobject / Table. I was making an example. In order to help, I'll need more information, or you'll have to ask the client to have access to their org so you can see what is going on. If you are pulling this from a formula, validate you are pulling in an ID and not the name of the record. If this is a formula, make sure to specify the Id as the last parameter, ie: AccountLookup__r.Id

Comment: By the way, it's a long shot, but are these cases you are dealing with? It almost looks like a Case Number.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be a custom AutoNumber field on an SObject/Table (custom or standard). That could give you a six-digit number.